# how to create generic (type and attribute) Spring Jpa Specifications

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Currently i am using spring data JPA with criteria API. I created a custom repository for an entity. The predicates are created this way 2 examples:

```
public static <E> Predicate matchingCountryOrGroup(CountryCode country, List<String> euGroups,
        SingularAttribute<E, String> countryAttribute,
        SetAttribute<E, String> countryGroupAttribute, Root<E> deliveryMode,
        CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    String countryGroup = country.getCountryGroup();
    Predicate countryGroupMatchPredicate = matchCountryGroup(countryGroup, euGroups, countryGroupAttribute, cb, deliveryMode);

    Predicate countryMatchPredicate = caseInsensitiveStringMatch(country.getCountryId(), countryAttribute, cb,
            deliveryMode);
    Predicate countryPredicate = cb.or(countryGroupMatchPredicate, countryMatchPredicate);
    Predicate bothNull = cb.and(cb.isNull(deliveryMode.get(countryAttribute)),
            cb.isEmpty(deliveryMode.get(countryGroupAttribute)));
    return cb.or(countryPredicate, bothNull);
}

public static <E> Predicate caseInsensitiveStringMatch(String match,
        SingularAttribute<E, String> stringAttribute, CriteriaBuilder cb,
        Root<E> deliveryMode) {
    return cb.equal(cb.lower(deliveryMode.get(stringAttribute)), match.toLowerCase());
}
```

I use these predicates in multiple queries for different attributes, thus the parameter for the attribute and different entities.
What is really annoying, is the fact that i always have to put in CriteriaBuilder and Root.

On the other hand i saw the Spring Specification API that seems to solve exactly this problem, by injecting the correct root and a CriteriaBuilder.

The question is: how can i leverage/use this Specification API with my kind of predicates - generic for different Entities and generic for different attributes?

**Updated question and code to add clarity**

Comment: There seem to be multiple questions here: The one asked in the title and the last sentence which you seem to have answered yourself and the question about getting rid of parameters of a `Specification`. Please clarify which is your question by removing the other one.

Comment: I want to get rid of these JPA criteria API parameters in the method signature. Specification API is exactly what is helping there, but how to use them in a generic way?

Comment: Sorry, this sounds to me like you just repeated the two questions.

Comment: what do mean - i often repeat question. once in title and again at the end of text? Is the question still not clear?

Comment: Correct. It is still not clear to me. I still see two very different questions.

Comment: I want my predicates implement as specifications - with generic Type(for entity) and additional parameters (to specify attribute used in query)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209140/discussion-between-jens-schauder-and-dermoritz).